# how to use ROBOCOPY to merge files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, robocopy

How can i merge multiple csv into 1 csv with logging in command prompt? ROBOCOPY provide logging feature but how do I merge multiple files into 1 file using ROBOCOPY command?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you cannot. Robocopy is used to get two folders in sync or to duplicate/move a folder contents.
To merge, you can use

```
REM see below link for details on /V /A options
copy /V /A file1.csv +file2.csv result.csv
copy /V /A file*.csv result2.csv
```

The [copy command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490886.aspx) will not modify the contents, so it implies all source file are in the expected format. The output will be like

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
        1 file(s) copied.
```

Is that enough for your logging needs ?